# How do I redefine a custom environment that I have previously defined elsewhere?

Tags: environments, document-classes, package-writing

I made a custom class for homework assignments and I've defined a solution environment as follows:

```
\def\qed{\ensuremath{\square}} % <-QED Symbol
\newenvironment{solution}{%  <-Solution
  \par\addvspace{1em}
  \itshape{Solution:}}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill\qed\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}%
```

This is intended to be a general purpose environment, but I am making a package specifically for use with math typesetting, and I'd like to slightly modify my solution environment when I load that package in this class... but I've tried the following and I get an error:

```
\let\solution\relax

\newenvironment{solution}{%  <-Solution
  \par\addvspace{1em}
  \itshape{Solution:}\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill\qed\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}%
```

The error I get when trying to compile a document is

> Command \solution already defined.

Comment: There is `\renewenvironment`. Otherwise you will need to `\let\endsolution\relax`.

Comment: Ah, good - I suppose it would have been nice to try that first. Thanks.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel please post an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The macro `\renewenvironment` is there to overwrite a previous defined environment (similar to `\renewcommand` and `\newcommand`).

Otherwise you will also need to `\let\endsolution\relax`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

% \newenvironment{<name>} defines \<name> and \end<name>
% and it checks if both are undefined (= \relax)
\newenvironment{solution}{stuff}{end stuff}

% Solution 1
% \renewenvironment{<name>} checks if both are defined (!= \relax)
\renewenvironment{solution}{other stuff}{end other stuff}

% Solution 2 (just for completeness)
%\let\solution\relax
%\let\endsolution\relax
%\newenvironment{solution}{other stuff}{end other stuff}

\begin{document}
    \begin{solution}
        content
    \end{solution}
\end{document}
```